# Ruby : NoMethodError: undefined method `split' on text file

Tags: ruby

I'am trying to load a txt file (line by line) into an array but I'm getting hit with NoMethodError error.

```
input_log = File.open("C:/text_file.txt", "r")
array1 = input_log.split("\n")
array1.each do |element|
  puts element
end
```

When you run this, I get

```
**:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `split' for #<File:C:/text_file.txt> (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'**
```

PS: Ruby Beginner - Pls help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.open` gives you an `IO` object that you can read contents from. You should read the file data and then `split` on those contents:

```
input_log = File.open("C:/text_file.txt", "r").read
array1 = input_log.split("\n")
array1.each do |element|
  puts element
end
```

For your task, it's better to use [`IO.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach):

```
File.foreach("C:/text_file.txt") do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: Thanks Arie, appreciate your help... looks like it reads everyline in the file and puts it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, tailored specifically to read multi-line files:

```
puts IO.readlines("C:/text_file.txt")
```

The function `readlines` is used to read the multi-line file into an array, each entry corresponding to a line in the file, which can be printed using `puts`.
You can read and put each line in the array as follows:

```
array = IO.readlines("C:/text_file.txt").map{&:chomp)
```

Comment: I've used ... array1 = input_log.readlines ... does this pose any issues?

Comment: It doesn't, but then you are accomplishing in 2 statements what you can do in 1. Even when u combine them, my version is shorter than `File.open("somefile.txt","r").readlines.map(&:chomp)`, and reads more like English (readlines from this file and chomp the newlines from it)...

Comment: cool..didnt know you could combine readlines& map directly into File handler stm .. thanks mate

Comment: @sqummer: Well, I hope it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **split** method on File Object directly

so you can try like this

```
array1 = []
File.open("C:/text_file.txt", "r").each do |test|
array1 << test.split("\n")
end
array1.each do |element|
  puts element
end
```